# Google visualization Chart x-axis not shown properly

Tags: charts, google-api, google-visualization

Anyone have  idea how to make the x-axis label shown properly like this ---> [correct x-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90Og8.png)

Currently x-axis label shown like this ---> [xAxis not shown properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g46a9.png)
It look like the x-axis lable is force to hide it.

This is my google chart code:

```
var ComboChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
          'chartType': 'ComboChart',
          'containerId': 'chart_div',

          'options': {
                       
              title: 'Weekly Yield',
         
              hAxis: {
         maxAlternation:8,
          showTextEvery:0,  
          slantedText:true,
          slantedTextAngle:90,

              },
     seriesType: "bars",
    series: { 1: {type: "line"}},    
          vAxis: {
                'title': 'Final Yield %',
                'titleColor':'#cc0000',
                        'titleFontSize':20
              }  
                  
          },
    'view': {'columns': [1,4,5]}
    });


    var ScatterChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
          'chartType': 'ScatterChart',
          'containerId': 'chart_div2',

          'options': {
            
            colors: ['#e0440e'],
              title: 'Weekly Delta',
         
              hAxis: { 
          slantedText:true,
          slantedTextAngle:90
              },
     
          vAxis: {
                'title': 'Delta',
                'titleColor':'#cc0000',
             gridlines: {count: 10},
                        'titleFontSize':20,
                            viewWindow: {

              
                   interval: 1,
                },

              }           
          },
   'view': {'columns': [1,6]}
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding more room to the bottom of the chart,
using the following option...

```
chartArea: {
  bottom: 72
}
```

Comment: sorry late reply  ,thanks for the answer  , but add 'bottom' option make whole chart shifted up and the tittle of the chart dissapear

Comment: you add `top` as well, top provide enough room for title, etc.